# $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$ acts transitively on $\partial \mathbb{D}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, group-theory

I was reading Complex analysis where I have a bit problem with the following statement "$\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$ acts transitively on $\partial \mathbb{D}$" can you please give me a hint related to this. Note that a group $G$ acting on a set $X$ is transitive if for every $x_1, x_2 \in X$ there is a $\gamma \in G$ such that $\gamma(x_1)=x_2$. Here $\mathbb{D}=\{z: |z|<1\}$ and $\partial \mathbb{D}$ is the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: Plane rotations, id est, multiplications by a constant of modulus $1$? (Obviously it should be $\gamma\in G$)

Comment: Thankzz  I got your point

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to give a detailed answer to this because I consider it a very nice example of group actions.

Note that we have a concise description of automorphisms of the unit disk:
$$\text{Aut}(\mathbb{D})=\{z\mapsto e^{it}\frac{z-w}{1-\bar{w}z}: t\in\mathbb{R},w\in\mathbb{D}\} $$

These are all maps that are defined everywhere, except the point $\frac{1}{\bar{w}}$ which has modulus strictly greater than one. Point being, these are maps that are well-defined on $\partial\mathbb{D}$ as well. The group action is
$$*:\text{Aut}(\mathbb{D})\times\partial\mathbb{D}\to\partial\mathbb{D} $$
where $f*\zeta:=f(\zeta)$.

The only non-trivial axiom of the action's definition we need to check is that we actually have $f(\zeta)\in\partial\mathbb{D}$ whenever $\zeta\in\partial\mathbb{D}$. Equivalently, it suffices to check that for any $w\in\mathbb{D}$ and $\zeta\in\partial\mathbb{D}$ we have $|\zeta-w|=|1-\bar{w}\zeta|$, but since $\bar{\zeta}\cdot\zeta=1$, we have $|1-\bar{w}\zeta|=|\zeta(\bar{\zeta}-\bar{w})|=|\zeta|\cdot|\overline{\zeta-w}|=|\zeta-w|$, as we wanted.

Now to check that the action is transitive, as you said, we need to take two fixed points $\zeta_1,\zeta_2\in\partial\mathbb{D}$ and find an automorphism $f\in\text{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$ such that $f(\zeta_1)=\zeta_2$. That is very easy! If we write $\zeta_1=e^{it_1}$ and $\zeta_2=e^{it_2}$ for $t_1,t_2\in\mathbb{R}$, we can take the automorphism corresponding to $w=0$ and $t=t_2-t_1$. This automorphism, geometrically speaking, is the rotation of the complex plane around the origin in an angle suitable for $\zeta_1$ to fall on $\zeta_2$ after our rotation.